# Not allowed to load local resource, embedded pdf in object

Tags: html, embed

I need to open pdf in my web page, the problem is that I get the files from another server so I tried to use `<object>` element with url to the PDF file, but it didn't work. So instead at first I download the pdf file to my server and then I tried to use

```
<object alt="pdf" border="0" data="d:/WEB/ASP/soubory/Download/189005864.pdf" 
        type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
```

But I am getting error. In chrome it says

> Not allowed to load local resource

and in IE

> Access denied

So I checked if the files I download are somehow restricted, but they arent and even if I rightclick on the link in my source code and select the "Open in new tab" option the browser poperly opens the pdf in new tab. So any ideas what may be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your web page (and more globally the browser through a web page) does not have the right to access your file system.
To access a file through a web page, you need virtual path and not a physical one.

Try something like `http://[Your server]/directory/yourPDF.pdf` as the src of your object.